# Student's t-distribution calculation

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

How to calculate this Student's t-distribution?

$X $~$ t(17)$

I have to find $P(X>8)$ and $a$ where $P(X>a)=0.1$.

I used standardizing for calculating similar probability for normal distribution $X $~$ N(18,3)$. How can I do that kind of thing here in Student's?

I know there exists the formula of $Z$ but don't know how to use it.

$\frac{\bar X-\mu}{S/\sqrt n}$

Thanks.

Comment: Standardizing, as mentioned at the end of your question,  works for almost any normal distribution by transforming the question so that it can be answered with printed tables of the standard normal CDF.

Comment: @BruceET What are the values for variables there in that formula?

Comment: [This Q & A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3962430/quantile-function-of-students-t-distribution-and-normal-distribution?rq=1) is not a duplicate, but may be of interest. It is linked under 'Related' in the margin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R, where `pt` is the CDF of a designated t distribution: for $X \sim \mathsf{T}(\nu=17),$ we have $$P(X > 8) = 1 - P(X\le 8) \approx 0,$$ as shown below. From most printed tables of t distributions one cannot get an exact value,
but from mine, one can see that $P(X > 3.985) < 0.0005.$

```
1 - pt(8, 17)
[1] 1.824967e-07
```

To find $a$ with $P(X > a)=.01,$ one can use the t quantile function (inverse CDF) `qt` to get $a =2.566934$ or look on line DF=17 of a printed t table
to find the value $2.567.$

```
qt(.99, 17) 
[1] 2.566934
```

The first question might be to find the P-value of a right-sided t test, the second to find the critical value for such a test at level $\alpha = 0.01 = 1\%.$

Most statistical computer programs give P-values, making it unnecessary to input a fixed significance level. Printed t tables give critical values for
tests at frequently-used significance levels, but cannot ordinarily be used to find exact P-values.

The following graph shows the density function of
$\mathsf{T}(\nu = 17)$ with value that cuts 1% of
probability from its upper tail.

```
hdr = "Density of T(17)"
curve(dt(x,17), -8, 8, ylab="PDF", xlab="t", 
       col="blue", lwd=2, main=hdr)
 abline(v = 0, col="green2")
 abline(h = 0, col="green2")
 abline(v = qt(.99, 17), col="red", lwd=2, lty="dotted")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually, I'm only interested in very basics. How do you calculate $P(x>8)$ from tables only?

Comment: @AlexJ if your value is greater than any value in the table consider the probability =0

Comment: Printed t tables have only a few values for each DF, so you can't generally work such problems from t tables. Please read my Answer: "From most printed tables of t distributions one cannot get an exact value,
but from mine, one can see that $P(X > 3.985) < 0.0005.$" So $P(X > 8)$ must be very small.

Comment: OK. By the way, can I use excel for this?

Comment: I suppose so, but I choose not to answer questions about details of Excel. // Early versions were clearly devil possessed. I understand it is better now after several successful exorcisms.

Answer (score 2):

If your distribution is a t with 17 d.o.f. you can directly use the tables. With 17 d.o.f. your distribution is very close to a Standard Gaussian thus $P(X>8)\to 0$

Here is a table to  understand what I mean. The student t is table [C-4](https://onlinepubs.trb.org/onlinepubs/nchrp/cd-22/manual/v2appendixc.pdf)

$$P(X>a)=0.1$$

Is $a=1.333$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can I solve $P(X>8)$ kind of thing in general? Can't I use only student t tables for this also?

Comment: @AlexJ: using  a calculator. For 17 d.o.f. you get $1.82497\cdot10^{-7}$.

Comment: How do you get that? I can't get.

Comment: @AlesJ: First block of R code in my Answer gives same answer as tommik gets from a calculator. Maybe your calculator just gives "$\approx 0$" or maybe you need to read its instruction manual.